# Bind ListBox in DataTemplate to parent control DataMemberBinding - Silverlight XAML

Tags: xaml, data-binding, silverlight-5.0

Just wondering if it's possible to bind the listbox in the XAML below to the GridViewDataColumn in a relative manner - I can do it explicitly but I want to add the Columns dynamically and would like to set up some logic in the the Column's Converter.

```
    <navigation:Page.Resources>
    <converters:DebugConverter x:Key="DebugConverter"/>
    <converters:DebugInnerConverter x:Key="DebugInnerConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ChemistryResultsTemplate">
        <ListBox><!-- Bind this to parent GridViewDataColumn data -->
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProfileResult}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</navigation:Page.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="LabReportGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding ChemistryResults, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}"
                                        CellTemplate="{StaticResource ChemistryResultsTemplate}"
                                        x:Name="Testing">
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</Grid>
```